# <b><big><br> etc. in Swift String

Tags: html, ios, swift, string

I am rewriting my Android app for iOS and have encountered a small problem. In android I had strings.xml file with html attributes and my strings looks like:

[image: strings in Strings.xml]

Now for iOS I made Localizable.strings and I have to made the same Strings like in Android.
How can I easy use attributes like `<b> <br> <big>` etc. in my Localization.strings ? I have a lot of strings and attributes to add, something like 6000 lines. How to make it easy as possible?

Comment: why would you want to add html tags to localizable strings? they are 2 different things, you should just Localize the strings, and then format the string by code

Comment: Because when I made it in my Android app in strings.xml I have everything easy to write and read, so I have to made it the same for iOS. If I will have to format very loooong strings programatic it would take too much time and cause disorder.

Comment: Probably in part yes, I'll try. I have to put it to "let" than load it, loading by func NCLocalizedString to array is okay?

Comment: I made it like "koen" said, it work for me but it change my String color to black and font size to very small, how to fix it? :)